# How to check if a string in a list is present in a particular column in a CSV file using python?

Tags: python, string, list, compare

I tried the following
here target_conditions is the list which is to be compared with a column in PLM

```
csv file
with open('PLM.csv', 'rt') as f: 
     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
     for row in reader:
        for str in target_conditions: 
             str=str.split(',')
             if str in row[3]: 
              print ("is in file") #but i need the patient name to be displayed
```

Comment: Is the patient name in row[3]? If so, then use `print(row[3])`.

Comment: Can you add a sample your csv file and target conditions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the code to find the value of target_conditions list from the column in PLM.csv file.

```
with open('PLM.csv', 'rt') as csvfile: 
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     for row in reader:
        for str in target_conditions:
            if str in row:
                print(row[row.index(str)])
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! it helped me :)